# VSCode autocomplete not working for OpenCV installed from source

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I've only found one other question asking exactly this with no answer, so I'm asking here.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, VSCode latest version.

I have installed OpenCV 3.4.9 from source to /usr/local

When I import cv2 and then try to type "cv2.", VSCode is unable to autocomplete. The only suggestions it makes are "bootstrap" and "os". I have no problem with autocomplete with any other module like numpy or rospy, or even when OpenCV is installed from pip. It seems the issue is only when OpenCV is installed from source.

I have tried both the language server as well as Jedi. I have also tried various linters.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

This is for those who have installed OpenCV on Anaconda and VSCode can't suggest cv2 functions.

`python.autoComplete.extraPaths` didn't work for me. so according to [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1993#issuecomment-398165987) :

1. open VSCode
2. ctrl + shift + p
3. type : `Python: Create Terminal`
4. type `python -m pip install --upgrade opencv-python` in the new terminal

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem. Hope this helps

Its because the package is not installed in the usual location but in a custom location. This problem could be resolved by some configuration changes. Configure the **settings.json** to include the custom location for autocompletion to work. Add path to `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`

STEP 1:Identify the location of the custom library/module.

STEP 2: Make the necessary changes in the User Settings or Workspace Settings file.

Here’s a sample entry in the User Settings (Mention the exact location of the module)

```
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/---/---",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/---/---/lib" ]
```

Comment: I have already added the path to the installed library to python.autoComplete.extraPaths. Still not getting autocomplete.

Comment: same here, any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Any response about this issue? I'm still having this problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue , has anyone got the solution ?

Comment: for windows i had my library at C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\opencv_python-4.3.0.38.dist-info

Answer (score 2):

In case of Ubuntu 20.04 and manual installation of OpenCV4, the python library path to be added to extraPaths is "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8". Assuming `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local` was used during cmake

Ex: "settings.json" (VScode)

```
{
"python.analysis.memory.keepLibraryAst": true,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8"
]}
```

Comment: If you don't know where opencv is installed you can print `cv2.__file__`

Answer (score 1):

@Karthik S was very helpful but I still couldn't make the intellisense work; adding

```
"python.jediEnabled": false,
```

Did the trick for me;

To sum up my settings.json file looks something like this:

```
{
"python.analysis.memory.keepLibraryAst": true,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"python.jediEnabled": false, 
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    
    "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8"
],
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft"
```

}

Hope it solves Your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many tickets, issues on the web and many of them find different solutions, here is mine. I faced exactly same thing with you.
Ubuntu 18.04 - OpenCV 4.7.0 build from source - Python - Vscode - Do not autocomplete

My VEnv path : */home/xxx/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so*

I put a symbolic link of *cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so* into system python which is in */usr/lib/python3.8*

( to do this you can simply
`sudo ln /home/xxx/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.8`
)

And adding python autocomplete extra path to settings.json as:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8"
],
```

to open settings.json:

[how to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZeU5.png)

And the last thing I did is, deleting Pylance extension from VSCode. This is the thing not written anywhere. After uninstalling Pylance extension suddenly everything is okay with autocomplete - intellisense OpenCV built from source. Now it works. I hope it works on your machine too.

Edit: Now I just find something different. I did not uninstall Pylance, but commented out a part in settings.json . That part is "python.analysis.extraPaths". There was a line automaticly generated same with I added before. When I commented it out, pylance and opencv intellisense worked properly.