# Autocomplete for cv2 not working properly in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, opencv, jedi

I'm trying to figure out why does the autocomplete for `cv2` package is not working properly. Below some information about issue and versions that I'm using and my attempts to solve it:

**Autocomplete in VS Code**

[image]

**Versions information**

- **opencv-python:** 4.4.0.46
- **jedi:** 0.17.2
- **numpy:** 1.19.4

All 3 packages above are installed at `C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

- **Visual Studio Code:** 1.50.1
- **Python extension:** v2020.10.332292344
- **Python version:** 3.8.3

**My attempts**

- I've checked whether my packages are installed in default location, suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428259/vscode-autocomplete-not-working-for-opencv-installed-from-source) with no success. They are installed at default location and still not working.
- The command line `print(jedi.Script("import cv2\ncv2.").completions())` brings me the auto-completion correctly when I execute it in PowerShell, as recommended in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/606), but still not working in VS Code. Result are below:

PS: I've limited the output because questions have a limitation regarding number of characters, can't bring them all.

```
>>> print(jedi.Script("import cv2\ncv2.").completions())
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated since version 0.16.0. Use Script(...).complete instead.
[<Completion: >, <Completion: absdiff>, <Completion: ACCESS_FAST>, <Completion: ACCESS_MASK>, <Completion: ACCESS_READ>, <Completion: ACCESS_RW>, <Completion: ACCESS_WRITE>, <Completion: accumulate>, <Completion: accumulateProduct>, <Completion: accumulateSquare>, <Completion: accumulateWeighted>, <Completion: ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C>, <Completion: ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C>, <Completion: adaptiveThreshold>, <Completion: add>, <Completion: addText>, <Completion: addWeighted>, <Completion: AffineTransformer>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_AGAST_5_8>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_AGAST_7_12D>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_AGAST_7_12S>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_NONMAX_SUPPRESSION>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_OAST_9_16>, <Completion: AGAST_FEATURE_DETECTOR_THRESHOLD>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_AGAST_5_8>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_AGAST_7_12d>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_AGAST_7_12s>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_create>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_NONMAX_SUPPRESSION>, <Completion: AgastFeatureDetector_OAST_9_16>, ...
```

- Have tried to update `numpy` package to the newest one (1.19) and also tried to use an older version (1.10). No success.

If anyone could give me a hint, I'll be glad, even to point where the issue really is (VS Code, python extension, jedi package).

And one last information: numpy autocomplete works normally.

Comment: What is the content you want to see in the autocomplete? And have you tried using other Python language services? For example: Extension: "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)".

Comment: I want to see the attributes and methods of `cv2` package, and none of them are shown. I'm also using `pylance`, forgot to mention it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue setting up my Jetson Nano 2GB, following the instructions via [Paul McWhorter](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGs0VKk2DiYxP-ElZ7-QXIERFFPkOuP4_). After uninstalling the python3-opencv package, this breaks cv2 completions.

I ran a trace and found that jedi could no longer find the library. My solution was to create a link to a location that it was looking for. I assume that there is a MUCH better way to fix this than my approach.

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2;ln -s python-3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so ./__init__.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
```

The paths & command syntax will most likely need to change to match your installed version of python.

Comment: How do I adapt your solution to Windows? And I'm also using Anaconda distribution

Comment: I'm using Linux so I can only provide a suggestion.  Locate the dist-packages/cv2 under anaconda, then instead of using a "link" just copy the file.  There should be a "python3.6" directory, copy the library in that directory to the dist-packages/cv2 directory as `__init__.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`

Answer (score 0):

I have looked on the Internet for a long time, but nothing worked for me. And here is a temporary solution.
Use stubgen to generate stubs for pylance.
Using pip to install stubgen:

```
pip install mypy
```

Then, using this command to generate stubs for pylance in your workspace:

```
python3 -m mypy.stubgen -m cv2 -o ~/Workspace/
```

Among this command, 'cv2' is the module you need to get the intelisense and autocomplete function.

hopes this helps.