# Why is python intellisense not working for some class functions like cascade classifier in vs code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Python IntelliSense not working for some class functions like cascade classifier in vs code. For most functions, it works but I am doing a project in OpenCV using python and when I am using haar cascade classifier function suggestions are not shown.

[The definition for detectmultiscale function is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W5C4.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode autocomplete not working for OpenCV installed from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428259/vscode-autocomplete-not-working-for-opencv-installed-from-source)

Comment: also check out https://forum.opencv.org/t/cv2-autocomplete-doesnt-work-in-vscode/4876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Language Server does not support [get Intesllisense from the pyd file](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1711) for now.

[image]

[image]