# VSCode C++ IntelliSense/autocomplete is not working for OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

OpenCV is installed from the source on my Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS) machine. The path is a bit different i.e. `/usr/local/<blah_blah>` and the directory tree looks somewhat like this:

```
milan@my_machine:/usr/local/<blah_blah>$ tree -L 4
.
├── bin
│   ├── opencv_annotation
│   └── ...
├── include
│   └── opencv4
│       └── opencv2
│           ├── ...
│           ├── core
│           ├── core.hpp
│           ├── ...
│           └── ...
├── lib
│   ├── cmake
│   │   └── opencv4
│   │       ├── OpenCVConfig.cmake
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.4.2
│   ├── libopencv_core.so.4.2 -> libopencv_core.so.4.2.0
│   ├── libopencv_core.so.4.2.0
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── opencv4
│   │   └── 3rdparty
│   │       ├── ...
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── python2.7
│   │   └── dist-packages
│   │       └── cv2
│   └── python3.6
│       └── dist-packages
│           └── cv2
└── share
    ├── licenses
    │   └── opencv4
    │       ├── ...
    │       └── ...
    └── opencv4
        ├── ...
        │   └── ...
        ├── ...
        └── ...
```

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63065476/) for PCL (Point Cloud Library) in the past and [my answer/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511979/) fixed that. So, I tried something similar:

In `settings.json`, I put:

```
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/**",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/core",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/*",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/**"
    ],
```

and in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file, I put:

```
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${default}"
            ],
```

However, doing this is not fixing the issue. C++ IntelliSense/autocomplete still does not work for OpenCV C++. So, how to fix this issue?

**Sample Code:**

[image: sample_code]

**Note1:**

- In `cmake`, `/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4` is used under `include_directories`.
- Compilation and execution work fine.

**Note2:** the following questions/issues are different from mine:

1. [VSCode autocomplete not working for OpenCV installed from source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60428259/) -- for OpenCV Python, not C++
2. [cv2 (opencv-python) intellisense not working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1993) -- for OpenCV Python, not C++

Comment: Is it working for other large libraries?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher other large libraries like? Could you please give some example? I just realized that IntelliSense/autocomplete is not working for `Eigen` library as well even though I added `"/usr/local/include/Eigen"` under `"C_Cpp.default.includePath"` in `settings.json` :(  Any suggestions?

Comment: I had a hunch that your Intellisense was not working at all, it was not an OpenCV glitch.  Check if Intellisense is enabled first. Do you see squiggles in OpenCV classes?

Comment: You mean squiggles in the `include` statements for OpenCV e.g. `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>`. I do see squiggles over there but don't see any anywhere else. On the other hand, I don't think IntelliSense is disabled. Because it works pretty fine for C++ STLs and other in-built C++ stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in my `settings.json` file, the `includePath`s were set like this:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/**",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/opencv2/core",
        .
        .
],
```

However, in my code, the headers were included like:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

If the `opencv2` folder needs to be included in the `#include` directive, the `includePath`s should look like this:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4",
        .
        .
],
```

So, the following `includePath`s configuration fixed the issue with IntelliSense/autocompletion for `OpenCV`:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4",
        "/usr/local/<blah_blah>/include/opencv4/**",
],
```

For a detailed explanation, take a look into the issue ([Issue 9900](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9900)) I created on `vscode-cpptools` GitHub page, particularly [this thread/reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9900#issuecomment-1253961016).

Special thanks to [`vscode-cpptools`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) and [`vscode-cmake-tools`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools) team!